# could not find the place to edit the celsius

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a svg of digital thermometer. I want to change the value as per the data the user provides. The place where i want to change the data is where 36.2 C is show. I tried to find by inspecting the elements from the browser but i see no such data where i could replace with the user provided values.

Here is the svg code

```
<svg width="148px" height="858px" viewBox="0 0 148 858" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient x1="99.9999529%" y1="75.0000427%" x2="-6.10879684e-06%" y2="73.6841544%" id="linearGradient-1">
            <stop stopColor="#BABDB6" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stopColor="#EEEEEC" offset="28.973272%"></stop>
            <stop stopColor="#BABDB6" offset="53.973275%"></stop>
            <stop stopColor="#555753" offset="75.234407%"></stop>
            <stop stopColor="#EEEEEC" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient x1="-8.03887317e-14%" y1="50.0000056%" x2="50.0000141%" y2="50.0000056%" id="linearGradient-2">
            <stop stopColor="#888A85" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stopColor="#888A85" stopOpacity="0.49803922" offset="30.906093%"></stop>
            <stop stopColor="#888A85" stopOpacity="0" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient x1="-7.27730447e-06%" y1="49.9999985%" x2="49.9999829%" y2="49.9999985%" id="linearGradient-3">
            <stop stopColor="#888A85" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stopColor="#888A85" stopOpacity="0.49803922" offset="28.077665%"></stop>
            <stop stopColor="#888A85" stopOpacity="0" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient x1="12.2424531%" y1="15.7534375%" x2="86.3876406%" y2="74.6575469%" id="linearGradient-4">
            <stop stopColor="#D3D7CF" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stopColor="#FFFFFF" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient x1="50.000025%" y1="148.064051%" x2="56.9301791%" y2="49.999923%" id="linearGradient-5">
            <stop stopColor="#555753" offset="0%"></stop>
            <stop stopColor="#555753" stopOpacity="0" offset="100%"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" strokeWidth="1" fill="none" fillRule="evenodd" sketchType="MSPage">
        <g id="Digital_Clinic_Thermometer_clip_art" sketchType="MSLayerGroup">
            <g id="layer1" transform="translate(0.028190, 0.304040)" sketchType="MSShapeGroup">
                <path d="M73.92597,770.21298 C82.1009,770.21298 85.47165,777.15586 85.47165,785.77996 L91.8927,840.91303 C91.8927,849.53714 82.1009,856.48002 73.92597,856.48002 C65.75104,856.48002 55.95924,849.53714 55.95924,840.91303 L62.38029,785.77996 C62.38029,777.15586 65.75104,770.21298 73.92597,770.21298 L73.92597,770.21298 Z" id="rect2610" fill="url(#linearGradient-1)"></path>
                <path d="M38.92421,551.31847 L109.63489,551.31847 L89.63489,818.64974 L58.92421,818.64974 L38.92421,551.31847 L38.92421,551.31847 Z" id="rect2605" fill="#3465A4"></path>
                <path d="M38.27775,550.30807 L108.98843,550.30807 L88.98843,817.63934 L58.27775,817.63934 L38.27775,550.30807 L38.27775,550.30807 Z" id="path3400" fill="url(#linearGradient-2)"></path>
                <path d="M51.59738,0.69596 C41.36284,5.15574 28.90161,15.26017 15.50363,36.41471 C4.87673,117.2425 0.91713,182.14454 0.97238,238.32096 C1.12513,393.63223 32.07874,376.25766 38.37863,550.41471 C40.15035,552.18643 44.06773,551.5969 46.09738,552.69596 L61.53488,588.69596 C61.53488,588.69595 66.93659,633.73549 73.94113,634.13346 C82.74764,634.44667 86.37863,588.69595 86.37863,588.69596 L101.78488,552.69596 C103.81541,551.5967 107.76246,552.18713 109.53488,550.41471 C115.83477,376.25766 146.78837,393.63223 146.94113,238.32096 C146.99638,182.14454 143.03678,117.2425 132.40988,36.41471 C119.0051,15.24944 106.52235,5.15226 96.28488,0.69596 L51.59738,0.69596 L51.59738,0.69596 Z" id="rect2599" fill="#EEEEEC"></path>
                <path d="M51.59738,0.9386 C41.36284,5.39838 28.90161,15.50281 15.50363,36.65735 C4.87673,117.48514 0.91713,182.38718 0.97238,238.5636 C1.12513,393.87487 32.07874,376.5003 38.37863,550.65735 C40.15035,552.42907 44.06773,551.83954 46.09738,552.9386 L61.53488,588.9386 C61.53488,588.93859 66.93659,633.97813 73.94113,634.3761 C82.74764,634.68931 86.37863,588.93859 86.37863,588.9386 L101.78488,552.9386 C103.81541,551.83934 107.76246,552.42977 109.53488,550.65735 C115.83477,376.5003 146.78837,393.87487 146.94113,238.5636 C146.99638,182.38718 143.03678,117.48514 132.40988,36.65735 C119.0051,15.49208 106.52235,5.3949 96.28488,0.9386 L51.59738,0.9386 L51.59738,0.9386 Z" id="path2618" opacity="0.71126757" fill="url(#linearGradient-3)"></path>
                <path d="M71,51.36218 L77,51.36218 C92.512,51.36218 105,63.85018 105,79.36218 L105,272.36218 C105,287.87418 92.512,354.36218 77,354.36218 L71,354.36218 C55.488,354.36218 43,287.87418 43,272.36218 L43,79.36218 C43,63.85018 55.488,51.36218 71,51.36218 L71,51.36218 Z" id="rect2613" fill="#3465A4"></path>
                <path d="M98.000005,101.862181 C98.000005,114.840873 87.4786966,125.362181 74.500005,125.362181 C61.5213134,125.362181 51.000005,114.840873 51.000005,101.862181 C51.000005,88.8834893 61.5213134,78.3621809 74.500005,78.3621809 C87.4786966,78.3621809 98.000005,88.8834893 98.000005,101.862181 L98.000005,101.862181 Z" id="path2616" fill="#D3D7CF"></path>
                <rect id="rect3418" fill="#9DC575" x="58.93311" y="143.87061" width="31.112698" height="136.47162"></rect>
                <rect id="rect3420" fill="#C6C6C5" x="55.39755" y="143.87061" width="4.2426395" height="136.47162"></rect>
                <rect id="rect3422" fill="#9B9D99" x="89.10645" y="143.87061" width="3.1819797" height="136.47162"></rect>
                <path d="M55,143.875 L55,153.875 L86,153.875 L86,280.875 L92,280.875 L92,153.875 L92.5,153.875 L92.5,143.875 L55,143.875 L55,143.875 Z" id="rect3424" opacity="0.41197187" fill="#555753"></path>
                <path d="M58.564933,844.881836 L58.2116627,846.863662 C58.2116627,851.874041 66.8684132,855.898388 74.0646311,855.898388 C81.260849,855.898388 89.8734547,851.874041 89.8734387,846.863662 L89.60849,845.348213 C89.5015955,845.350332 89.4070937,845.348213 89.2993805,845.348213 L62.3184234,845.348213 C60.9957026,845.348213 59.7235637,845.180608 58.564933,844.881836 L58.564933,844.881836 Z" id="path3483" opacity="0.5422535" fill="#555753"></path>
                <path d="M13.3772206,217.209829 L12.1769991,218.254467 L11.2657198,217.209829 L12.1547728,210.964232 L13.1105047,210.964232 L14.088463,212.120001 L13.3772206,217.209829 M14.4663105,209.363937 L13.1771837,210.519706 L12.2214518,210.519706 L13.0882784,204.274109 L14.2884999,203.229472 L15.1775529,204.274109 L14.4663105,209.363937 M22.045487,202.896077 L20.8674918,203.940714 L15.5554004,203.940714 L14.6663474,202.896077 L15.8443426,201.85144 L21.156434,201.85144 L22.045487,202.896077 M22.3566555,210.519706 L21.4009236,210.519706 L20.4229653,209.363937 L21.1342077,204.274109 L22.3344292,203.229472 L23.2234821,204.274109 L22.3566555,210.519706 M21.4231499,217.209829 L20.2229284,218.254467 L19.3116491,217.209829 L20.0451178,212.120001 L21.3342446,210.964232 L22.2899765,210.964232 L21.4231499,217.209829 M19.8450809,218.587862 L18.6448594,219.632499 L13.3549943,219.632499 L12.4659413,218.587862 L13.6439365,217.543224 L18.9560279,217.543224 L19.8450809,218.587862 M25.2453831,218.543409 L24.0673879,219.588046 L23.1561086,218.543409 L24.2229722,210.964232 L25.1787041,210.964232 L26.1566623,212.120001 L25.2453831,218.543409 M26.5345099,209.363937 L25.2453831,210.519706 L24.2896511,210.519706 L25.3565147,202.940529 L26.5345099,201.895892 L27.4457891,202.940529 L26.5345099,209.363937 M32.0466382,209.297258 L30.8241904,209.297258 L27.5346944,205.47433 L27.8680893,203.007208 L28.4682,203.007208 L32.2911278,207.4747 L32.0466382,209.297258 M34.4248549,210.519706 L33.4691229,210.519706 L32.4911647,209.363937 L33.402444,202.940529 L34.5804391,201.895892 L35.4917184,202.940529 L34.4248549,210.519706 M33.2913123,218.543409 L32.0910909,219.588046 L31.2020379,218.543409 L32.1133172,212.120001 L33.402444,210.964232 L34.3581759,210.964232 L33.2913123,218.543409 M82.5865207,209.363937 L81.4085255,210.408574 L80.4972462,209.363937 L81.2307149,204.274109 L82.4087101,203.229472 L83.3199894,204.274109 L82.5865207,209.363937 M82.1419942,202.896077 L80.9417727,203.940714 L74.9851179,203.940714 L74.0738386,202.896077 L75.2740601,201.85144 L81.2307149,201.85144 L82.1419942,202.896077 M81.030678,210.741969 L79.8304565,211.786606 L75.1629285,211.786606 L74.2738755,210.741969 L75.474097,209.697332 L80.1416251,209.697332 L81.030678,210.741969 M81.4974308,217.209829 L80.2972093,218.254467 L79.4081564,217.209829 L80.1193987,212.120001 L81.3196202,211.075364 L82.2086732,212.120001 L81.4974308,217.209829 M79.9193618,218.587862 L78.7413666,219.632499 L72.7847118,219.632499 L71.8734325,218.587862 L73.073654,217.543224 L79.0303089,217.543224 L79.9193618,218.587862 M95.0103412,202.896077 L93.8101197,203.940714 L88.5202546,203.940714 L87.6312017,202.896077 L88.8091968,201.85144 L94.1212883,201.85144 L95.0103412,202.896077 M87.4311647,209.363937 L86.142038,210.519706 L85.186306,210.519706 L86.0531327,204.274109 L87.2533542,203.229472 L88.1424071,204.274109 L87.4311647,209.363937 M86.3420749,217.209829 L85.1418534,218.254467 L84.2305741,217.209829 L85.1196271,210.964232 L86.075359,210.964232 L87.0533172,212.120001 L86.3420749,217.209829 M92.8099352,218.587862 L91.6097137,219.632499 L86.3198485,219.632499 L85.4085693,218.587862 L86.6087908,217.543224 L91.8986559,217.543224 L92.8099352,218.587862 M94.3657778,217.209829 L93.1877827,218.254467 L92.2765034,217.209829 L92.9877457,212.120001 L94.1879672,211.075364 L95.0992465,212.120001 L94.3657778,217.209829 M93.9212514,210.741969 L92.7210299,211.786606 L87.3867121,211.786606 L86.4976591,210.741969 L87.6978806,209.697332 L93.0099721,209.697332 L93.9212514,210.741969 M98.6769901,218.498956 L97.4989949,219.543594 L96.5877157,218.498956 L96.7432999,217.454319 L97.9212951,216.409682 L98.8325744,217.454319 L98.6769901,218.498956 M103.781054,204.829767 L102.580838,205.874404 L101.669559,204.829767 L101.758459,204.274109 L102.95868,203.229472 L103.847733,204.274109 L103.781054,204.829767 M110.715667,202.896077 L109.515451,203.940714 L104.225586,203.940714 L103.314307,202.896077 L104.514529,201.85144 L109.804394,201.85144 L110.715667,202.896077 M111.182426,209.363937 L109.982204,210.408574 L109.093151,209.363937 L109.804394,204.274109 L111.00461,203.229472 L111.893663,204.274109 L111.182426,209.363937 M109.648809,210.741969 L108.448582,211.786606 L103.11427,211.786606 L102.225217,210.741969 L103.425433,209.697332 L108.73753,209.697332 L109.648809,210.741969 M102.02518,217.209829 L99.6469636,219.299104 L100.669369,212.075549 L101.847364,211.030911 L102.758649,212.075549 L102.02518,217.209829 M109.426546,219.632499 L99.9359058,219.632499 L102.314117,217.543224 L107.626214,217.543224 L109.426546,219.632499 M135.807804,204.829767 L134.607582,205.874404 L133.718529,204.829767 L133.785208,204.274109 L134.98543,203.229472 L135.874483,204.274109 L135.807804,204.829767 M134.696487,202.896077 L133.518492,203.940714 L128.206395,203.940714 L127.317348,202.896077 L128.495343,201.85144 L133.807429,201.85144 L134.696487,202.896077 M127.117311,209.363937 L125.828179,210.519706 L124.872447,210.519706 L125.739279,204.274109 L126.939495,203.229472 L127.828553,204.274109 L127.117311,209.363937 M126.028215,217.209829 L124.828,218.254467 L123.91672,217.209829 L124.805768,210.964232 L125.7615,210.964232 L126.739458,212.120001 L126.028215,217.209829 M132.496076,218.587862 L131.29586,219.632499 L126.005995,219.632499 L125.116942,218.587862 L126.294937,217.543224 L131.607023,217.543224 L132.496076,218.587862 M134.07415,217.209829 L132.873929,218.254467 L131.962644,217.209829 L132.051555,216.654171 L133.251771,215.609534 L134.140829,216.654171 L134.07415,217.209829" id="flowRoot3558" fill="#000000" transform="translate(73.570101, 210.741969) rotate(90.000000) translate(-73.570101, -210.741969) "></path>
                <path d="M93.4717318,102.612188 C93.4717318,113.228041 84.8658825,121.83389 74.2500294,121.83389 C63.6341763,121.83389 55.028327,113.228041 55.028327,102.612188 C55.028327,91.9963347 63.6341763,83.3904854 74.2500294,83.3904854 C84.8658825,83.3904854 93.4717318,91.9963347 93.4717318,102.612188 L93.4717318,102.612188 Z" id="path3572" stroke="#BABDB6" strokeWidth="1.11959003" fill="url(#linearGradient-4)"></path>
                <path d="M58.21951,798.86525 L59.68826,818.334 L90.40701,818.334 L91.87576,798.86525 L58.21951,798.86525 L58.21951,798.86525 Z" id="path3657" fill="url(#linearGradient-5)"></path>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The long i have posted because you can copy paste and create a svg and see what i could not find.

Here is the image file

http://svgshare.com/s/1Bw

Comment: ctrl + f and then paste what's inside quotes 'M13.3772206,217.209829 ' and here's this line

Comment: It's the line that @MantasČekanauskas pointed out.  It has either been drawn by the artist, or was some text using an LCD font, that has been converted to outlines.  If you need to edit it, you will have to do that as well.